# Converting multiple date formats into one formatin Excel with pthon

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, csv, date

In one huge Excel file, I have two different "date formats", for example 17.08.2022 and 2022-08-17.
These dates are all written in one column, I want to write all of them in the same format (preferably in this format, 17.08.2022) and rewrite them in the same column.
How should I do it?
Please have it in mind that I am not good at writing code :(.

Comment: Please note that stackoverflow isn't supposed to ask others write code for you. If you have a specific question on your trial you should add the code you've done till now as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `17.08.2022` format are not actual dates but text. Anyway you can try to highlight the column -> Data -> Text to Columns -> Next -> Next -> Date: DMY > Finish.

Comment: Thanks for answer yes it helps.
But in that case, I have to do it every time that new Excel rows added to this huge Excel file. 
I have already had a small python code to merge and transpose the data inside that Excel sheet, so I thought maybe I can add another line to change the date format, to make all date formats the same.

Comment: In that case you should provide that python code so we can see what you already have